# Make While Loop Shoot Back Up To Top

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

So, I'm working on a C++ assignment for my Intro to Computer Science class.

In the program I want there to be a loop that can shoot back up to the top anytime I want, sort of how you can do it with a Boolean in example:

```
bool1 = true;
while (bool1){
    bool1 = true;
}
```

Is there anyway I can mirror this effect in a While loop that is set to depend on a numerical value like:

```
while(x > 99)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about setting `x = 100` ?

Comment: what does "shoot back up to the top" mean?

Comment: `bool1 = true;` is not a flow control statement, it's an assignment. Whatever it is you think is happening here, I'll put money on it being wrong.

Comment: Repeat back to the beginning.

Comment: If you want to make sure you loop repeats itself when a specific condition is true, you can change the condition to add a OR. Instead of just `x>99` you can have `x>99||bool1` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment:

> Repeat back to the beginning.

If you want to go to the start of the `while` loop, use `continue;`

```
while(x > 99)
{
   // Do your stuff.
   // ...
   // Upon some condition, go to the beginning.
   if ( some_condition_is_true )
      continue;

   // Otherwise, proceed with the normal execution of
   // the loop.
   // ...

}
```